# Im getting a error in Laravel after find and replacing some syntax

Tags: php, laravel, github, rename

I just tried renaming a form submission git to vampire

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Vampire;

class VampireController extends Controller
{

/**
 * Display a listing of the prducts.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $vampires = Vampire::all();
    return view('vampires.index',compact('vampires',$vampires));
}
```

I get a error saying

```
"Class 'App\Vampire' not found"
```

Comment: Did you change the file name as well?

Comment: @Benson Can the last closing bracket be the issue in this?

Comment: compact should be compact('vampires')

Answer (score 0):

The issue doesn't appear to be in `VampireController.php`. There are three things to check.

1. Make sure you have the correct file at `app/Vampire.php`
2. Verify the namespace: at the top of `app/Vampire.php` you should see `namespace App;`
3. Verify class name: `class Vampire extends Model`

It could be a minor typo, so be sure everything matches up exactly. If all else fails, a `composer dump-autoload` never hurts.

Comment: Now im getting InvalidArgumentExceptionView [vampires.index] not found. even though my index is next to my create folder

Comment: That's good! That means your original error is solved. `view('vampires.index')` is looking for a file at `resources/views/vampires/index.blade.php`. That error tells me it doesn't exist. One thing to note is the `.blade.php` naming convention is important.